# How to Resolve Port 53 Conflict Between, systemd.resolved and pihole-dnscrypt docker

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, docker, pi-hole

**Problem**: port 53 conflict between systemd.resolved and pihole in the pihole-dnscrypt docker

**Setup**: pi 4, ubuntu 20.04.2 (clean install)

**Guides for install**:

(1) `https://github.com/losuler/pihole-dnscrypt-docker`

(2) `https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole/` (section - Installing Ubuntu)`

**Attempted Solutions**:

(1) Stop resolution via stub listener:

`sudo sed -r -i.orig 's/#?DNSStubListener=yes/DNSStubListener=no/g' /etc/systemd/resolved.conf` (from the second guide).

**Breaks name resolution on the server**.

```
bullwhip@bravo:~/dockers/pihole-dnscrypt-docker$ curl prdel.cz
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: prdel.cz

bullwhip@bravo:~/dockers/pihole-dnscrypt-docker$nslookup prdel.cz   
;; reply from unexpected source: 127.0.0.1#53, expected 127.0.0.53#53
```

**Clients browsers can't connect when I set their DNS servers to the IP of the pihole-dnscrypt server**.

```
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

(2) Shut off systemd.resolved:

```
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved

sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
```

**Breaks name resolution on the server**.

```
bullwhip@bravo:~/dockers/pihole-dnscrypt-docker$ curl www.prdel.cz
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.prdel.cz

bullwhip@bravo:~/dockers/pihole-dnscrypt-docker$ nslookup prdel.cz
;; reply from unexpected source: 127.0.0.1#53, expected 127.0.0.53#53
```

**Clients browsers can't connect when I set their DNS servers to the IP of the pihole-dnscrypt server**.

```
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

(3) Repeat step 2 and remove symlink from /etc/resolv.conf to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf by creating a static /etc/resolv.conf.

This seems to work, but it doesn't seem to be a good solution, as I'm loathe to simply do away with systemd-resolved, as Debian/Ubuntu have it there for reasons.

I'm pretty new to linux networking/admin, so I've looked wherever I can think of on the net to find a solution. No luck so far.

I would appreciate any guidance on this.

Thanks!

Comment: If the `pihole-dnscrypt docker` has a GitHub site, I think I would probably try that first - submit an "issue", read their wiki, etc.

Comment: Thanks @seamus. I definitely will do so. I checked there before posting here, and I only saw one issue that never really was resolved. I didn't want to cross-post unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you find the solution since then...

Although others might be interested in knowing how to work around this. So, for those who (like me) didn't carefully read the pihole official docker hub container image page where there is a section that explained it called "Installing on Ubuntu", here a direct link to that section on the github project:

https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole#installing-on-ubuntu

Good luck!